# Change comma and thousand separator in tick labels

Tags: r, plotly

In a chart like the one below I wan to change the thousand separator to a dot ".", but I don't know how to use the `tickformat` parameter in order to get it.

```
require(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(x=~c(2012,2013,2014,2015,2016), y=~c(1200000,975000,1420000,1175000,1360000), type='bar') %>%
     layout(yaxis = list(title="Income in €", tickformat=",d", gridcolor = "#bbb"), xaxis = list(title="Year"), margin=list(l=80))
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know if you use `tickformat`, [`separators`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-separators) gets ignored. So you can either specify your `tickformat` or your `separators`.

```
require(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(x=~c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), y=~c(1200000, 975000, 1420000, 1175000, 1360000), type = 'bar') %>%
  layout(separators = '.,', 
         yaxis = list(title='Income in Euro'))
p
```

[image]

Comment: Ok! If I use `separators=",."` then the decimal separator is comma and the thousands separator is dot, but in this case, how can I show in the tick labels the whole figure with all the digits and not abbreviated?

Comment: You cannot as far as I know. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: There is already a bug filed for that issue: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1264